# Fill width of button inside collection view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there an easy way of doing this? I'm using storyboard to align a button inside a cell manually (set width/height) trying to get it to fit inside a cell within a collection view. The problem is that while it may fit one version of iphone, example iPhone 6 it doesn't fit on iPhone 5 - different resolutions and all.

Is there a Swift way of forcing the button width to fit inside cell, as in fit the full width of the cell?

Comment: Could you give us a little more details on how your UI is? It would be great if you could show us a screen shot with the relevant part of your storyboard.. =D

Comment: Use constraints to pin the edges of the `UIButton` to the cell. Just make sure you have enough other constraints so the cell can size itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, delete the width constraint (if you have one). Then pin the button to the edges and set constraints:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Agree! I would like to know more about how the UI is though... And also, instead of using -20, it'd be better to uncheck the "constraints to margin" check box and set the constraints to 0.

Comment: So much easier with your method, thank you. I managed to get it to fit properly after a few trial and errors. I have a related question if you don't mind me asking, if I have 3 buttons (1, 2 and 3) with button 3 being added last and they're all on the same line.. How do I get button 1 and 2 to show up ontop of button 3?

Comment: @user3591436 When you say "on top" do you mean vertically in the view?

Comment: No I mean actual view. I have 3 buttons, the 3rd button is overlapping button 1 and 2. I rather have button 1 and 2 overlap button 3.

Comment: @user3591436 In the document outline, drag button 3 higher in the list than buttons 1 and 2. Although You may want to use more constraints so you don't have any overlap (unless that's the look you're going for)